# Winter Bash explanation is in Russian?

Tags: support, localization, winter-bash-2017

When I open [the Winter Bash site](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) it shows all in Russian. But I am not, neither is my browser nor my Windows system and I am in Argentina.

[image]

Comment: @SPArchaeologist my name seems to be originating from France. The Winterbash site is in English for me.

Comment: @rene there is no French.SO afaik. This is likely localization becoming too greedy in trying to auto identify user location, they better just remove it and try other route, e.g. if user has active account (with rep and posts) in one of the localized sites.

Comment: There is no geolocation, the site just goes with whatever language the browser requests. Are you sure you haven't set your browser to request Russian as the primary language?

Comment: I am in Argentina.

Comment: Show your `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: For instance, you can check [here](http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php). But maybe your ancestors were from Russia :)

Comment: @Abyx: The result is: *de-DE,de;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,es-AR;q=0.7,es;q=0.6*

Comment: @Abyx: I removed Russian the the list of accepted languages and now it shows in Spanish which is fine. Thanks.

Comment: @juergend worthy of self answer then, so others can do the same if it happens to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Abyx comment I got the *accepted languages* from my Chrome Browser with [this site](http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php). The result was:

```
de-DE,de;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,es-AR;q=0.7,es;q=0.6
```

which indicates that first German is accepted, then Russian, then Spanish.

So I changed that in the Browser config like this:

```
Chrome Settings -> Extended -> Language
```

There I removed Russian and added English.

Comment: How did it happen that your browser had Russian as accepted language?

Comment: I think because I chose the "Translate" button once in Chrome when visiting a russian site.

Comment: [Pues funciona bastante bien para mí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T7wD.png). :)